# My website content not getting fetched via Curl (fetch via url)

Tags: curl, web, subdomain, urlfetch

My website content is not getting fetched. I am using CURL script to check the fetching, also checking in sites like Facebook. But except my website all other website's content is getting fetched. Previously it was working. Now I have shifted to sub-domains like london.website.com, paris.mysite.com etc. Can anyone tell me what is causing this ?

Comment: Lot of people earlier posted questions that they couldn't perform `curl` on `http://localhost/` from their server. May be you are dealing with the same issue. You can try doing the curl from your local PC and check whether you can access the URL or not.

Comment: I am using getting location from IP and redirecting to the respective subdomain. Is there any problem in that ?

Comment: If you are redirecting, then you have to handle `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` from curl. Or `-L` from curl commandline. Can you update your question with your code(or command) and with an example url?

Comment: But the problem is other site are not able to fetch my website. Why so ?

Comment: Can I have the link? Can the browse the site from browser?

Comment: can you come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50449/url-fetch